Многосайтовость Битрикс
Подскажите, пожалуйста, такая ситуация: на битриксе был один сайт (один домен). - site1.ru
Приобрела второй домен, настроила симлинки, в админке битрикса добавила сайт. -site2.ru
При переходе по адресу site2.ru/bitrix
перенаправляет на адрес site1.ru/index.php
Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

А при переходе просто на site2.ru перенаправляет на site1.ru?
Первым делом стоит проверить редиректы, скорее всего какой-то из них срабатывает.

А в настройках сайтов домены прописаны?
